Ms detours, modified rax register on returning
So my code is setup like this.
Hook:
DetourTransactionBegin();
DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
DetourAttach(&Objects_orig, Objects_detour);
DetourTransactionCommit();

Detour:
void Objects_detour(uint64_t a1, int a2, int a3) {
    return Objects_orig(a1,a2,a3);
}

Def in header:
void Objects_detour(uint64_t a1, int a2, int a3);
typedef void(*Objects_deb)(uint64_t a1, int a2, int a3);
inline Objects_deb Objects_orig = nullptr;

In exe before:
.exe+24267F - CC                    - int 3 
.exe+242680 - 44 89 44 24 18        - mov [rsp+18],r8d
.exe+242685 - 89 54 24 10           - mov [rsp+10],edx

After:
.exe+24267F - CC                    - int 3 
.exe+242680 - E9 F3DAFEBF           - jmp 7FF766E50178
.exe+242685 - 89 54 24 10           - mov [rsp+10],edx

So about that RAX register. When I set breakpoint normally it contains pointer to the gamedata, at 242685. Now after I hook it and set break after it contains 0.
if I change to void* Objects_detour RAX is now some pointer, but it doesn't contain gamedata nor nothing interesting. So my question is what I am doing wrong? It shouldn't change RAX?

I would say that rax is a caller-saved register and thus cannot be expected to be preserved across a method call? And thus, it should not make a difference if the detour changes it for a void method. (Otherwise rax is the return value and needs to be meaningful, of course.)

That explains why function itself runs fine. Nothing is missing then.
